# How can i improve the complexity of this r function?

Tags: r

I'm working in a classification problem so i developped in r this hashing code :

```
    # The used packages 

        library("pacman")
        pacman::p_load(dplyr, tidyr, devtools, MASS, pracma, mvtnorm, interval, intervals) 
        pacman::p_load(sprof, RDocumentation, helpRFunctions, foreach , philentropy)       


    # data-matrix

        frids <- data_frame(
          name = c("Nicolas", "Thierry", "Bernard", "Jerome", "peter", "yassine", "karim"),
          age = c(27, 26, 30, 31, 31, 38, 39),
          height = c(180, 178, 190, 185, 187, 160, 158),
          married = c("M", "M", "N", "N", "N", "M", "M")
        )
        i <- Intervals(
          matrix(
            c(0,5000,  
              0,5000,
              7000,10000,  
              7000,10000,
              7000,10000,
              10000,15000,  
              10000,15000
            ),
            byrow = TRUE,
            ncol = 2
          ),
          closed = c( TRUE, TRUE ),
          type = "R"
        )
        frids$salaire = i
        frids


       # The basic function that we will call in the hashing process   

        hash<-function(v,p){

        if(dot(v,p)>0) return(1) else (0)  

        }



    # The hashing process

    LSH<-function(data,K,L){

    # We subset the matrix with only numerical columns df.r

    t<-list.df.var.types(data)
    df.r<-as.matrix(data[c(t$numeric,t$Intervals)])

    # n is the number of rows / observations that we are studying

    n=nrow(df.r)
    print(n)
    print(ncol(df.r))

    # we build a matrix from N(0 ,1 ) law 

    rn=array(rnorm(K*K*L,0,1),c(K,K,L))

      # rd is a matrix that contains integers from 1 to k 
      # it's used to get a combinaison of columns / a subset of the observation in the case we have a high dimension 

rd=unique.array(array(unique(ceiling(runif(K*K*L,0,ncol(df.r)))),c(K,K,L)))

    print(rn)
    print(rd)
    print(df.r)

# Now we build the hashing tables 

    buckets<-array(NA,c(K,n,L)) 
    for (h in 1:L) {
      for (i in 1:K) {
        for (j in 1:n) {
          buckets[i,j,h]<-hash(df.r[j,][rd[,i,h]],rn[,i,h])
        }
      }
    }
      print (buckets)
    return(buckets)
    }
```

**My question is that :**

I think the complexity of the LSH function is : **O(LKn)** , where k is the number of the attributes i choosed for the hashing and n is the number od observations ( rows ). L is the number of bands/hash tables ( dimensions = k*n ).

How can i improve the complexity performance or the excecution time of the LSH function ?

**For example :**

If n=1.000.0000 of observations instead of n=7 , how much time the excecution will require ?

Running example :   `z1=LSH(frids,3,2)`

K=3  ; foreach iteration we take three columns between (age , height , salaire.1 , salaire.2) .

L=2  ; we build 2 hashing tables in total. The tables consists of 0 & 1 .

[image]
[image]

**Computing example :**

In the last hashing table , the first element at the second row :

```
(i , j , h ) = (2 , 1 , 2 )

buckets [i , j , h ]=buckets [2 , 1 , 2]

buckets [i , j , h]=hash( df.r[j,]rd[,i,h] ; rn[,i,h]] )

=hash( df.r[1, c(3,4,2)] ; c(-2.99 , 0.64 , 0.51 ) )

= hash( dot ( c(0 , 5000 , 180) ; c(-2.99 , 0.64 , 0.51) )

=1
```

Sorry but my knowledgne in this field is limited.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Can i for example use lapply / vectorize or any built-in function that will give me good results in hight dimensions ( ex : n=1.000.000 instead of n=7 ) ?

Comment: Why do you need a hashing function at all? Out of curiosity. If you don't need to implement this, look into the native R implementation of hash functions, i.e. use lists after creating a new environment with `new.env(hash=TRUE)`.

Comment: R built-in hash functions aren't fitting my situation . Hashing is just a little step in my work. My problem is the performance of the nested loops in high dimension and how can i get a reasonable excecution time.

Comment: Nested loops and R are not a good combination. If you really want performant code and your code requires nested loops, consider implementing your hashing function in C++ and using `Rccp`

Comment: I don't know what is Rccp.  I think there is a way to use lapply or vectorize instead of loops

Comment: @csgroen , simply do you mean that R isn't fitting high dimensions so i should change the language of implementation.

Comment: Mouad, R can easily call C or C++ code, so you can replace the R code for the loops with a function written in C/C++ for greater speed -- that's what csgroen is alluding to.

Comment: @Robert Dodier  , thank you . now i understand!

Comment: Yes, that's what I was saying. But maybe also look at hashing implementations in R from packages like hash or dict. You don't need to reinvent this kind of stuff ;)